# I have trouble adding react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable in to my project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Image,
  Switch,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { Swipeable } from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';

const Test = () => {
  return (
    <Swipeable>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Im a test page</Text>
      </View>
    </Swipeable>
  );
};

export default Test;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
  },
});
```

Comment: import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, Image, Switch, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Swipeable } from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';


const Test = () => {
    return (
        <Swipeable>        
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Im a test page</Text>
        </View>
         </Swipeable>

    )
}

export default Test

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
        flex: 1,
        width:'100%'
       
    },
});

Comment: Please try to take the opportunity of updating description. It lets people help better.